# My script runs only once, I want unlimited times without reloading the html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, click

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Animations</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css">

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">


      $(document).ready(function(){

            $(".box").on("click", function(){

              $(".container").addClass("animated rollIn");
             //$(".container").addClass("rollIn"); we have the same result


            });



            $("#join_us button").on("click", function(){

              $(this).addClass("animated shake");

            });


        });

    </script>
</head>
```

Why the two functions are executed only at the first time (only once) each of them when I click the box and button of my html page? Do you have any solution? I searched a lot here the topics but I didn't manage to fix the problem.

P.s.: sorry for any mistake if any, it's the first time I post a topic.

Comment: Do you mean to remove the classes on second click? If yes then you should be using `toggleClass` instead of `addClass`

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you asking that why they are executed only one time in the lifecycle of the document? or are you asking how to toggle the class.

Comment: Once you add a class, adding it again won't do anything.

Comment: No, the two click events simply make an html box and a button being animated . I want this to happen not only once but many times without ofcourse reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, where the class is added in `setTimeout`

```html
<div class="container">DIV 1</div>
<button class="box">Roll In</button>
<div id="join_us">
  <button>Shake It</button>
</div>

<link href="https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".box").on("click", function(){
        $(".container").removeClass("animated rollIn");
        setTimeout(function(){
          $(".container").addClass("animated rollIn");
        },1);
    });
    $("#join_us button").on("click", function(){
      var button = $(this);
       button.removeClass("animated shake");
        setTimeout(function(){
          button.addClass("animated shake");
        },1);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Ohh!!!! It worked now! The setTimeout is a function of jquery library? I should learn manipulate it. I thought it was simple but finally it is a little complicated. Thank u very much , mylee!

Comment: Welcome! `setTimeout` is native javascript function, the second parameter is the time in milliseconds